# Create named arrays from JSON

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, pdo, echarts

I'm fetching data from a MySQL DB and encode it as JSON before passing it to a Javascript class. The data will be used to display charts. The chart does need arrays, and I'm looking for a method to create the needed arrays from my JSON object without creating every array manually and pushing values into it.

My Object looks like this:

```js
var myJSON = [
        {"name1": "value11", "name2":"value21", "name3": "value31"},
        {"name1": "value12", "name2":"value22", "name3": "value32"},
        {"name1": "value13", "name2":"value23", "name3": "value33"}
]
```

And I would like to look it like this:

```js
var myData = {
"name1": ["value11", "value12", "value13"],
"name2": ["value21", "value22", "value23"],
"name3": ["value31", "value32", "value33"],
}
```

I know how I could create the needed arrays and push the values into them, but I am hoping there is a more elegant solution to this. I have looked into the Map function and familiarized myself with Object.keys and Object.entries but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Basically I think this can and should be solved in javascript, but I also tagged the question with Mysql/PDO because I could fetch the data differently if that is an option.

I've been trying since friday, hoping there is an elegant solution, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change it on the server to the preferred format. Saves on transferred bytes too. This can and should be fixed on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` with `forEach` and `Object.entries`:

```js
var obj = [
  {"name1": "value11", "name2":"value21", "name3": "value31"},
  {"name1": "value12", "name2":"value22", "name3": "value32"},
  {"name1": "value13", "name2":"value23", "name3": "value33"}
]

console.log(obj.reduce((a, o) => (Object.entries(o).forEach(([k,v]) => a[k] ? a[k].push(v) : a[k] = [v]), a), {}))
```

> `reduce` will loop over each object, keeping each previous value inside `a`.
>
> `Object.entries` will return a key value pair of each object inside your array.
>
> `forEach` will loop over pair, and push the values to the `a`ccumulator.

The one liner, broken down by linebreaks:

```js
var obj = [
  {"name1": "value11", "name2":"value21", "name3": "value31"},
  {"name1": "value12", "name2":"value22", "name3": "value32"},
  {"name1": "value13", "name2":"value23", "name3": "value33"}
]

console.log(
  obj.reduce((a, o) => (
    Object.entries(o).forEach(([k,v]) => 
      a[k] ? a[k].push(v) : a[k] = [v]
    ), a
  ), {})
)
```

Comment: This produces exactly the desired output while looking like the most elegant solution. I think I understand what is going on, except for the last "a" variable. Does the last "a" hold the complete object again with its current values from this iteration ?

Comment: The last `a` makes use of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). It evaluates the first expression, and returns the last. So it returns the accumulator, on each iteration. So essentially, you're right :)

Answer (score 1):

> tagged the question with Mysql/PDO because I could fetch the data differently if that is an option.

Yes, that is.

To get such an array You need to [combine FETCH_GROUP with fetch_COLUMN](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce into an object, iterating over the `Object.entries` of the array item, creating an array at the key in the accumulator if necessary, and then pushing to that array:

```js
var myJSON = [
  {"name1": "value11", "name2":"value21", "name3": "value31"},
  {"name1": "value12", "name2":"value22", "name3": "value32"},
  {"name1": "value13", "name2":"value23", "name3": "value33"}
];

const output = myJSON.reduce((a, obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    if (!a[key]) {
      a[key] = [];
    }
    a[key].push(val);
  });
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This should really be done on the server in my opinion